# Failed to initialize local MSP: admin 0 is invalid: could not obtain certification chain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I get this error when I am starting an `orderer`.

```
Failed to initialize local MSP: admin 0 is invalid: could not obtain certification chain: An X509 certificate with Basic Constraint: Certificate Authority equals true cannot be used as an identity
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the `orderer` running on a separate node from where I have generated the admin certs.

Possible this means that the admin certs on the `orderer` are invalid, or doesn't exist. For me it was expected to be in the following folder: `[orderer org]/msp/admincerts/cert.pem` but was not.

Ensure that admin certs generated for your `orderer` are correct, whether they are generated by cryptogen or with `fabric-ca`.